# Подключить in-app в os x

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, in-app-purchases

Добрый день, пишу свой первый проект на `Swift` под `OS X`.
Не нашел толковой документации, есть она для `Object C` или под `ios`?
Возможно кто-то сталкивался? Буду благодарен.
Сертификат разработчика у меня есть, `itunes connect` настроен.

Comment: можете скинуть ссылку на пример документации на objC, чисто чтоб понять какого характера документацию вы хотите

Answer (score 1):

С толковой документацией не очень хорошо.
Пример более-менее понятный есть у [Рэя](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial).
По личному опыту: обязательно ещё делать проверку чеков на своём сервере, 90% судя по логам приходит "поддельных" покупок.